# Declare array of array in loop typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

On my app I have an object of dates which contains time array like 
Console log output is as follows

```
32: {
1514160000: Array [ 1200, 1500 ],
1514764800: Array [ 1200, 1500 ],
1515369600: Array [ 1200, 1500 ],
1515974400: Array [ 700, 1200, 1500 ],
1516579200: Array [ 700, 1200, 1500 ],
}
```

With this data I have implemented loop to create a new array of dates with time and worker id as follows ( similar to this )

```
1514160000 :[
1200 : [32,40,56],
1500 : [32,40],
],
1514764800: [
1200 : [32,40,56],
1500 : [32,40],
]
```

I have written following code for this where I want to create array of dates by dynamically assign dates and then create it an array again.

```
let allDates :any = [];
      for(let pid in this.allAvailableProviders)
      {
        console.log(pid);
        for(let slotDate in this.allAvailableProviders[pid]){
          if(!Array.isArray(allDates[slotDate])){
            let allDates[slotDate] :any = [];
          }
        }
      }
```

where allAvailableProviders is object

It gives me following error on ng serve

```
'=' expected
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: You have to assign the value, not store it in a variable, let allDates[slotDate] :any = []; should be allDates[slotDate] = []; to initialize an empty array at this index.

Comment: Why are you adding typing if you're setting it to `any`?

Comment: what you want? you want any data type or array data type?

Answer (score 2):

You are just initializing the array. There is no assignment or need for let:

```
    for(let slotDate in this.allAvailableProviders[pid]){
      if(!Array.isArray(allDates[slotDate])){
        allDates[slotDate] = [];
      }
    }
```

Comment: This fixes their compilation/parsing problem, but you should warn them that their code is not using the benefits of a type system.

Answer (score 1):

The `let` statement is followed by a variable name, not an expression.

You should just define your outer array as the right type, instead of `any`. You know it's an array of arrays.

```
  let allDates: any[][] = [];
  for(let pid in this.allAvailableProviders)
  {
    console.log(pid);
    for(let slotDate in this.allAvailableProviders[pid]){
      if(!Array.isArray(allDates[slotDate])){
        // You'd get an error if you assigned something that is not an array.
        // because you specified the type correctly
        allDates[slotDate] = [];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the difference between `let allDates: any[][] = [];` and `let allDates: any = [];`??

Comment: `const x: any[][] = 3` will fail compilation and so will `const x: any[][] = [3]`; Your code is saying that variable can take any type, my code is saying it has to be an array of arrays.

Comment: Am asking what about `const x: any= 3` vs `const x: any[][] = [3]`??  because it compiling as same right?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Not sure what you are saying, I already  explained to you that I'm adding actual types so that compiler can help you. `const x: any[][] = [3];` will fail compilation because the compiler expects the array to contain other arrays, but you are putting in a number